# Accessing parent window through Javascript (when child window's URL is on another server)

Tags: javascript

I understand that ajax can't go cross-server.

So I am trying to just access my parent window, like change its location.  So it works when the child page is on the same server but not when it is on another server.

For example:

parenttest.html:

Click here

childtest.html

opener.document.location="http://www.cnn.com";

So this works when childtest is on the same server but not when it is on another server.  Why can't I even access the opening window that popped up the pop-up window?

thanks

Comment: Ok, it didn't show the parenttest.html properly.

Comment: in parenttest.html , I am just putting a link around click here with target = "_blank"

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to format code so that HTML tag aren’t removed.

Comment: If you want to access opener, it can't be opened with a link, it should be opened using window.open (I think)

Answer (score 1):

[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is not going to let it happen.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to run your code as you mentioned (server a opening a popup on server b, then having the popup change the location of opener). However, I tried the same thing with an iframe. Loaded google and tried to change it cnn.com. It allowed me when I used

```
window.frames.myframe.location = 'http://www.cnn.com'
```

It didn't work when I tried

```
window.frames.myframe.document.location = 'http://www.cnn.com'
```

Try removing document from your statement. Maybe there are a few things you can do to a window from a different domain. I know you can at least test if window.closed

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/HrWer/

**New test**

I started from wikipedia.com, typed into the URL box:

```
javascript: open('http://www.google.com');void(0)
```

From the window that opened, I typed the following statements into the URL box

```
javascript: alert(opener.closed) //false, it works

javascript: alert(opener.location.href) //undefined, access denied

javascript: opener.document.location = 'http://www.google.com'; void(0); // Didn't change the location, access denied

javascript: opener.location = 'http://www.google.com'; void(0); // YES, it changed
```

I think this almost confirms my theory, I only tested in chrome though.

Comment: I am sorry.  I am not that familiar with this site.

Comment: I think I found a way to do it.  I am just going to have to tell the people on the other sites to include an iframe to my site.  That is the only way I have gotten it to work.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello Christina, it takes some getting used to. Each question is supposed to benefit anyone in the world, not just the person asking the question, that's what makes this better than most forums out there. The best thing you could do is delete your comments from epascarello's answer, add the one that says what you tried here. Regarding your question: I got it to work with a popup like the second  example I posted. Did you make sure to open the popup using window.open()?

Comment: If I remove document from my statement, it pops up a new window for some reason instead of accessing the parent window. I would like to use an iframe so I can stay on the same server, but I am using Adobe Captivate, and it doesn't seem like it works well in an iframe. That's why I have to pop up a new window on a different server.

Comment: @Christina: Thanks for fixing the comments